# Array validation in yii2?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using dynamic form in yii2. My posting data is an array like this

```
[ModelAddress] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fullname] => xxxx
                [lastname] => xxxx
                [date] => 15 Apr 1985
                [DOB] => 09 Jan 1985
                [percentage] => 20 %
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [fullname] => xxx
                [lastname] => xxxx
                [date] => 15 Apr 1985
                [DOB] => 09 Jan 1985
                [percentage] => 20 %
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [fullname] =>xxxx
                [lastname] => xxx
                [date] => 15 Apr 1985
                [DOB] => 09 Jan 1985
                [percentage] => 20 %
            )
```

I want to check total percentage must be 100. But i am using compare validation it is validate each percentage.But i want to total percentage.
My form like this

```
 <?php foreach ($modelsAddress as $i => $modelAddress): ?>
            <div class="item panel">


                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                         <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]fullname")->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]lastname")->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]date")->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]DOB")->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
                             </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]percentage")->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Please help any one.Thanks in advance

Comment: Do You want to check sum of percentage attributes in all records? So for provided example validated value will be 60%?

Comment: thank u for reply.Yes i want check sum of percentage in all records.yes  provided example validated value will be 60

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally write my own validation in controller.

```
 $postvalue = Yii::$app->request->post();                         
          foreach ($postvalue['ModelAddress'] as $value) {
                $total = $total +$value['percentage'];
          } 


          if($total != 100)
          {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Percentage Must be 100');
          }else{
            return $this->redirect('/Home');
          }
```

Comment: And You'll in each actions, which should contain this rule, paste this block of code? If validation rule applies to model attribute, in my opinion of course, it should be written in this model as it was shown in others answers. But it's Your code ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you post the models, each one is validated separately, do you need to write a custom validation that checks all the post data of the same model. Something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        [['percentage'], 'validatePost']
    ];
}

public function validatePost($attribute)
{
    $posts = Yii::$app->request->post($this::formName());
    $total = 0;

    if (is_array($posts)) {
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $total += $post[$attribute]; // I'm assuming values are numbers

            if ($total > 100) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'It\'s over 100%.');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u for reply .i check it and inform u how it works

Comment: I just made a quick test here and si working fine. Did you noticed my comment? The values of percentage are just numbers or you are sending as `"30%"` (string with `"%"`)? If that's the case, you just need a few adjusts to handle the string.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done outside a model. I suggest you add it to your controller or as a helper component.

```
private function validatePercentage($models) {
    if (array_sum(ArrayHelper::toArray($models, "percentage")) != 100) {
        array_walk($models, function($model) {
            $model->addError("percentage", "All percentages must add up to 100%");
        });
    }
}

public function actionAdd() {
    // instantiate your models and do initial validation
    if ($this->validatePercentage($models)) {
        //Do saving or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u for reply When i call validatePercentage() it's goes inside the function but validation not working.form is submitted